# A lack of line breaks in browser's source view using html-express-js template engine

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine

I am not experienced in express js template engines and I tried to choose a simple one from the list https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

I chose `html-express-js` that is on GH:  https://github.com/markcellus/html-express-js

I implemented it in my own code, but when I ran it, there were no line breaks in Chrome source view. So then I implemented the example code from the `html-express-js` GitHub site, but then the same bad issue happened.

The picture of the issue:

[image]

I need the line breaks there, and I think it is normal for the most HTML sites.
Is it a simple way to get the line breaks in this template engine? Or could anyone indicate a good template engine from the list?

Below I insert I think the crucial example files

*example/public/index.js:*

```js
import { html } from '../../src/index.js';

export const view = (data, state) => html`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      ${state.includes.head}
      <title>Dashboard</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>This is the dashboard!</h1>

      <p>
        This file is served by the <code>staticIndexHandler</code> in app.js
      </p>

      <p>Click <a href="/hello">here</a> to go hello route.</p>
    </body>
  </html>
`;
```

*example/app.js:*

```js
import express from 'express';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import htmlExpress, { staticIndexHandler } from '../src/index.js';

const __dirname = resolve();

const app = express();

app.engine(
  'js',
  htmlExpress({
    includesDir: 'includes',
  })
);

app.set('view engine', 'js');
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/example/public`);

// serve all other static files like CSS, images, etc
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/example/public`));

app.get('/hello', async function (req, res) {
  res.render('hello', {
    name: 'world',
  });
});

// Automatically serve any index.js file as HTML in the public directory
app.use(
  staticIndexHandler({
    viewsDir: `${__dirname}/example/public`,
    notFoundView: 'not-found', // OPTIONAL: defaults to `404/index`
  })
);

export default app;
```

Comment: `I need the line breaks there` -- why? Line breaks have no meaning in html and are generally removed as an optimisation step before sending html to the browser. Removing line breaks generally reduce the size of html and js anywhere between 15% to 50% due to removal of spaces/tabs used for indentation. What is the reason you want a slower website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html()` function of `html-express-js` template engine will replace the `\n` and `\r` with `''` globally from the HTML template string. See this line [v1.1.1/src/index.js#L65](https://github.com/markcellus/html-express-js/blob/v1.1.1/src/index.js#L65):

```js
export function html(strings, ...data) {
  let rawHtml = '';
  for (const [i, str] of strings.entries()) {
    const exp = data[i] || '';
    rawHtml += str + exp;
  }
  const html = rawHtml.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
  return html;
}
```

You can use [ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs) or [Pug](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) template engine. Please choose the famous libraries, they are usually more full-featured, well-tested, and well-maintained.